# activting object from another scene in UNity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble with a project in Unity.  I want to show (it's not visible before that) a button in one scene after clicking on another button in another scene.

Example: THe game is for more than one person, and one of the players (Player1) has one scene shown, another player(Player2) has another scene opened in front of him. The first player want's to give permission to the other player (Player2)  to use (only once) something from his scene. So the first player is clicking on a button to Activate the object/button to the other player. After the other player uses the object/button function, the button is hidden again and not usable, until the first player gives permission again.

How do we make the activation process to the other scene?

Comment: Player 1 and 2 are playing on the same machine, like 2 controllers local multiplayer? or is it a network / internet multiplayer ?

Comment: am... it should be local, as there is a leader/master (scene 1) and the rest of the players are having scene 2.   But if you have a solution for the same machine, you can Bring it on :), as for the moment I just have to show it how it should work. :/  and I will still learn something new, no matter on which way you can give me a solution.

Comment: For now, it still works on the same machine, it's only a mockup and I don't know if the project will continue, so maybe, for now, the solution for the same machine will be better. (+ I will use it probably in the future as I will try to understand what it is doing, instead of only copying)

Comment: I never used Unity to make a local game like that, so I need to ask some questions to understand the architecture :) .  So, it seems that it is the same "instance of the game" (on an computer executable file point of view) running. That should make this somehow simpler, if it possible at all. 
What you need is what we may a call a class that acts as a _service_, and that is a singleton, instanciated once at the beginning of the game, and that is _shared_ among scene.

Comment: The simplest way would probably be to create a static class? (with static fields, static methods etc...). I have a feeling that is not best practice, you may encounter some "run condition" at some point, but it may be good enough for a proof of concept. Store the shared information in this `static class`, and make it `public` so that all scenes can access it. You might need something ("controller script as usual") in each scene that regularly checks this static class, since you won't have the usual `Update` method and such directly in the static class itself)

Comment: Yes, I just now tried it. It works with static. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I turned my comment into a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that this is a **local** multiplayer, you need to use some **shared object** inside the program.

The simplest course of action, as far as I see, is to use some `static class`.

Store the shared information in this static class, and make it public so that all scenes can access it.

You might need something (some kind of controller script, as usual) in each scene that regularly checks this static class, since you won't have the usual `Update` method and such directly in the static class itself.

It's probably not the best architecture, but it should be good enough for a proof of concept at the very least. Depending on what you do, it might be good to use completely.